# Lua / corona sdk physics.addBody()

Tags: lua, coronasdk

When my ball hits but 30 targets 30 new returns except I have an error message lua:76: physics.addBody() cannot be called when the world is locked and in the middle of number crunching, such as during a collision event why ?

```
function CreeNiveau()
    print("Crée  le Niveau 1 ")

    local lig,col ,x,y
    local largeurColonne = (display.actualContentWidth/(5+1))

    x = display.screenOriginX + largeurColonne
    y = display.screenOriginY + 100

    -- si une cible et toucher la Remove et donne des point

    local function onToucheCible(self, event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        audio.play(sonBump)
        self:removeSelf()
        AjouteScore(25)
        nbCible = nbCible - 1
        print("Nombre de cible restent", nbCible)
        if nbCible == 0 then
            Recible()
        end
    end
end


for lig = 1,6 do  
    for col = 1, 5 do

        local cible = display.newCircle(x,y, 8)
        -- couleur des cible
        cible:setFillColor(1,math.random(),math.random())
        physics.addBody( cible, "static", { density = 1, friction = 0.3, bounce = 0.6, radius = 8})
        cible.collision = onToucheCible
        cible:addEventListener("collision")
        globaleview:insert(cible)
        x = x + largeurColonne
    end 

    y = y + 50
    x = display.screenOriginX + largeurColonne
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably use physics functions/APIs in collision listener. Use [`timer.performWithDelay`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/performWithDelay.html) to delay execution of `Recible` function:

```
local function onToucheCible( self, event )

    if event.phase == "began" then

        audio.play( sonBump )
        self:removeSelf()
        AjouteScore( 25 )
        nbCible = nbCible - 1
        print("Nombre de cible restent", nbCible)

        if nbCible == 0 then

            timer.performWithDelay( 50, Recible )

        end

    end

end
```

Read more:

- [physics.addBody() cannot be called](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/59210-physicsaddbody-cannot-be-called/)
- [physics.addBody cannot be called when the world is locked and in the middle of number crunching such as during a collision event](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/57116-physicsaddbody-cannot-be-called-when-the-world-is-locked-and-in-the-middle-of-number-crunching-such-as-during-a-collision-event/)